# is it possible to achieve a bit-wise compatibility of rendered bitmaps across different OS/hardware (from the same scene)

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I did some test by rendering Blenders' pure initial scene (with plain cube) on my two different Dell laptops. Then I tried to compare rendered BMP or PNG images byte-by-byte - and there were some pixels (bytes), which are slightly different between these two images, unfortunately.

Is it possible to have exactly the same byte-wise compability of rendered bitmaps from the same, simple scene - but between different hardware? That could be even done by using some additional modification in Blender code, for my personal use.

I need it only for grayscale PNG/BMP (BW mode), and only for such a simple scene like initial Blender scene.

Comment: It should be identical, if you're using the same version of Blender and use the same seed for the integrator (and otherwise identical project settings)

Comment: May I ask, what you want to achieve? What benefit do two identical files have? The byte difference are not pixels values, but metadata.

Comment: I use the same version of Blender. I didn't play with seed - I suppose it was set to default value: 0. But I rather thought about using Eevee renderer (not Cycles) - due to short rendering time...

Comment: The byte difference is not only for metadata, but also for many pixels (I made some short C program for binary comparision of both these files to verify it better).
I would like to have the same output from hash function for both binary files (i.e. modified files, which consists informations about pixels only, extracted from plain BMP or PNG)